# Why is build tasks not showing up in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

Hi I'm doing Unreal 5 Udemy Course and in video it is this image[image: image of build tasks listing specifically win64 development build]

But when I try it looks like this
[image: image of build task list not showing]

I am changed to MSVC version v14.30 - 17.0 so that my UE5 live coding works but i don't think that is why build tools are not showing. But not sure how it would be fixed. What can it be do you know?

[image]

Comment: Did you create this project yourself inside the Unreal Engine? If not you should Generate Project Files. You need to have set your IDE to VSCode inside the Unreal Engine before doing this so it creates the correct project files. Even if you haven't you should do it after changing your IDE to VSCode inside the Unreal Engine.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you haven't build anything, as I understood.

You need to make something like that in your dir
[Workplace look with correct tasks.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFzNJ.png)

{PathToYourUeProjDir}/.vscode/tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "UnrealGame Mac Development Build",
            "group": "build",
            "command": "/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_5.0/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Mac/Build.sh",
            "args": [
                "UnrealGame",
                "Mac",
                "Development",
                "-waitmutex",
                "-architecture=arm64"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "dependsOn": [
                "UnrealBuildTool Mac Development Build"
            ],
            "type": "shell",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        },
      ]
}
```

You may need to correct "command" path, it is path to your ue5.

And you may also need to correct options.cwd, here I'm not sure

Then you just build with cmd+shift+B.

Keep in mind that I installed the xcode version 13 (it is still recommended by UE) from apple dev. And in xcode-preferences-locations I set up command line tools to xcode13. I'm not sure is it crucial, but that is the way it works for me now.